# Anotar un dataframe

Tags: r

La verdad es que no tengo mucha experiencia en programanción con R.
Les comento mi problemática

Dispongo de dos dataframe
DF1 con las siguientes variables: HPO y enfermedad
DF2 con las siguientes varibles :  HPO

Me gustaría añadir en el DF2 otra variable con el nombre de la enfermedad cuando los HPO coincidan

Muchas gracias por la ayuda
Un saludp

Comment: Hola para poder ayudarte, puedes compartir el código de lo que haz intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Bienvenida Clara a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Revisa con el buscador por preguntas antiguas, ya hay varias respuestas al respecto que te pueden ayudar, básicamente lo que buscas es un `left join` entre dos `data.frame`, algo así `merge(x = DF2, y = DF1, by = "HPO", all.x = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Buen día, pondré como ejemplo los siguientes `DataFrames`

```
DF1<-data.frame(HPO=c(1:5),
                enfermedad=c("Apendicitis","Gripe","Diabetes","Dolor de cabeza","Dolor de muela"))

DF2<-data.frame(HPO=c(2,2,4,1,1,1,2))
```

Ambas puedes unirlas mediante la función `merge`:

```
merge(x = DF1,y = DF2,by = "HPO")
```

Aquí "**x**" e "**y**" representan las tablas que deseas unir y **HPO** el nombre de la llave primaria y foránea en cada tabla (en este caso ambas se llaman **HPO**)